# ignore child div with jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Please suggest on below.

I have written

```
var demo= $("div#side-bar ul li").find('a').find('img').parent().text();
```

which works fine. But giving me output as: " maximize".
I want  USERNAME_TO_PRINT in answer

```
<div id="side-bar" >
    <ul>
        <li alt="User options">
            <a href="#" name="nav1">
                <img alt="ppawar" src=" Myprofile.png" /> USERNAME_TO_PRINT
            </a>
            <div class="jx-arrow-up"></div>
            <ul id="nav-1" style="display: none;">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img align="absmiddle" src="maximize.png" />
                       Maximize
                    </a>
                    <div class="jx-arrow-up"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not properly formed. While making it readable I noticed there's a rogue `</div>`

Comment: `$("#side-bar > ul > li > a").text()`, you should make `USERNAME_TO_PRINT` in a container

Answer (score 1):

With your HTML fixed (that `</div>` removed), telling jQuery to find only direct descendants will get you the string you want.

```
var demo= $("div#side-bar > ul > li > a").text();
console.log(demo);
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rg7Xw/)

Comment: some how this code is not working where i actually wanted use it.
i am using greasemonkey script to return user name on page load.

Comment: We can only answer questions to the extent that they are described. That info isn't in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to select an element.  Popnoodles' answer is correct, this will work too:

```
var demo = $("div#side-bar ul li a:eq(0)").text()
console.log(demo)
```

Answer (score 0):

All these loooooong hand query selectors are okay - but do you really want to write code like that ?

If you have the ability to add a name to a close element `<a href="#" name="nav1">` then why not

`$('a[name=nav1]').text();`

Edit: missed to send the selector as a string -- thanks @pop : )

Comment: No, I shouldn't! That's not what downvoting is for at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `:first` or `.first()`.

Comment: where? how? Please post comments in the comment section, answers shouldn't generate questions.